# "monotone" versus "symplectic Fano"

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-geometry

Hi. I have a question about the notion "symplectic Fano". 
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold with a $\omega$-tamed almost complex structure $J$. According to "J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology, by D.McDuff and D.Salamon, pp 388 - 389",  $(M,\omega,J)$ is called "symplectic Fano" if for any $A \in H_2(M)$ which can be represented by a $J$-holomorphic curve, $\langle c_1(M), A \rangle$ is positive. (Note that $J$-curve that I meant is not just a rational curve. The genus of the curve can be positive.)

On the other hand, $(M,\omega,J)$ is called "monotone" if $[\omega] = \lambda c_1(M)$ in $H^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ for some positive $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is obvious that if $M$ admits a monotone symplectic structure, then it is symplectic Fano. My questions is as follow.

Q : Does "symplectic Fano" imply the existence of a monotone symplectic structure?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited.** For the definitions that you mention "Simplectic Fano" can be non-montone. For example, you can take a $4$-dimensional Kahler  non-agebraic torus that does not have complex curves at all. Such a torus does not have complex curves at all and it is has no symplectic structure for which it is monotone. The same trick can be done with K3 surface

Comment: Yes the word Fano is not correct but what he really wants is: $w(A)$'s all have the same sign over classes that can be represented by J-holomorphic curves.

Comment: Mohammad, you are right I misread the question. But now it works :) 

Comment: you were right, my examples were wrong. 

Comment: I deleted them. 

Comment: So the questions is if $\pm c_1$ is positive on any $J$_holomorphic curve, is itself a symplectic form?

Comment: Or saying better, does it have a representative which is a symplectic form. This question is related to Kleiman's criteria for ampleness on varieties. Kleiman's theorem says (under some mild assumptions):

If $w^k$ is positive on any sub variety of dimension $k$ then $w$ is a kahler form.

But here we only have the condition above for curves and not symplectic manifolds of any dimension.

Comment: Mohammad, I understand this question as follows: Suppose $c_1$ is positive on all $J$-holomorphic curves (for some $J$), is it true then that we have a symplectic form $\omega$ on M such that $\omega=\lambdaC_1(M)$? It could be possible, to get further examples using discrepancy with Kleiman's theorem, for example if you find a Kahler manifold such that $(C_1(M),\Sigma)>0$ for all complex curves $\Sigma$ but $C_1(M)^{1/2 dim M}=0$.

Comment: Exactly, an example like what you mentioned at the end is the answer.